# Find a word (not a character ) in a string?

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript code :

```
var a = 'how are you';
if (a.indexOf('r') > -1) 
{
    alert('yes');
} 
else {
    alert('no');
}
```

This code `alert('yes')`. It only matches the character `'r'` is present in the string or not. But I want to match a full word(like `'are'`) not a character. How I can do this?

Comment: Did you try `are` instead of `r`?

Comment: change it to `a.indexOf('are') > -1`

Comment: That would also match 'hare', 'dare', 'bare', 'scare', ...

Comment: Yes I tried. But it only matches char

Comment: Really?  `"apple".indexOf("are")`  `--->` `-1`

Comment: If I understand it right you want to match "are" in "how are you" but not to match it in "gare du nord". If so you should improve your question to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Read MDS

> #### [`str.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)
>
> **searchValue**
>
> A  *string representing* the value to search for.
>
> **fromIndex**
>   The location within the calling string to start the search from. It can be any integer between 0 and the length of the
>   string. The default value is 0.

So `(a.indexOf('are') > -1)` should work that will return 4 for `a` = `'how are you'`.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
var str = "how are you";
var n = str.search("are");
```

or do u want  algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `a.search("are")`.

```
var a = 'how are you';
if (a.search('are') > -1) 
{
  alert('yes');
} 
else {
  alert('no');
}
```